# Securing Tomcat Webapps

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, tomcat, sql-injection

Given a database (MySQL) driven webapp written entirely in vanilla J2EE (no frameworks etc), which has no attempts at security (except a basic database login system). What steps should you take to secure it?

Any resources about this would also be handy. (I've found OWASP).

Thanks!

Comment: SQL injection and information in cleartext that shouldn't be are the first two that comes to my mind.  They're respectively OWASP's number 1 and number 7 ; )   Given that's it's a webapp you obviously want to read quite a bit about CSRF and XSS.  What's not to like about OWASP?

Comment: @user988052 Nothing, it's an absolutely fantastic resource, but I've already found that. So interested to see what else is out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be a loaded question.

The Spring Security framework is the first thing that comes to my mind, but it appears you might not be inclined to using any frameworks.

If you want to manage the security yourself using a set of database tables, then you would probably want to spend some time designing a proper data model that accounts for users and roles.

You would probably want to create some sort of Servlet filter that will check to see if a logged in user exists for protected resources.  If the user exists, then the filter would forward to the protected resource.  If the user is not authenticated, then the filter would capture the target page and redirect the user to authentication page.

Some other things to consider:

a).  You would probably need to setup ssl for any page that passes login credentials.

b).  You would probably want to look into some encryption facility for storing a users password.

c).  Being that you are writing a Java EE app, you want probably want to look into managing user principles.

d). if you are deploying to a distributed environment, how will you handle session management.  In other words, should the sessions be sticky? or will you employ some sort of shared memory space for authenicated users( i.e. WebSessions, Database persistance, etc)

e). Pay special attention to sql injection attacks;  if you are using jdbc prepared statements, this wouldn't be much of a concern.

f). If you are processing credit card transactions, you would want to make sure that you are PCI compliant

g). Beware of evil bots, try to limit bot activity wherever possible. This can usually be done by employing some sort of captcha utility

h). If you are using any third party tools/frameworks be sure that you are always updated with the latest releases to avoid vulnerabilities

Here are some resources that come to mind:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jce/JCERefGuide.html

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/ssl_faq.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbwk.html

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't very clear, I meant more protecting against possible attack vectors rather than writing a secure login system, but the resources and the things to consider look very useful! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Roy Kachouh: It's not a loaded question: simply because a Java developer isn't using a framework doesn't mean the question is loaded...  *"You would probably need to setup SSH for any page that passes login credentials"*: you were thinking about HTTPS (with TLS/SSL), not SSH ; )

Comment: @user988052 yes, you were right...i meant ssl, corrected it :)  And the loaded remark had nothing to do with the fact that he is not using any framework.  The loaded remark was based on the fact that security in general is a broad topic and contains several varying aspects.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @RoyKachouh. I didn't mean it to be loaded, it's just quite a broad area. Is there any security benefit to using Hibernate over JDBC?

Comment: Hey @Reu, i can't immediately think of any security benefit you will gain by using hibernate instead of straight JDBC. At the end of the day, hibernate is built on top of JDBC.  The only thing I can think of  is that hibernate is a humongous open source community.  Therefore, they might have dealt with or be more adept at dealing with security than developing something from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement is very abstract: You have already mentioned  [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Java_Project) which takes care of security of a web application in general. Some of the most common attacks on a web applications are following

1. Cross site scripting (XSS)
2. SQL injection
3. Insufficient Transport layer security (not using HTTPS)
4. Brute force hacking (*no restriction on number of login attempts*, *not using [captcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha)*)
5. Denial of service attack.

There are many more but these are most common. OWASP addresses most of these. Now to secure your web application from each of these attacks, please go through theory part (Google the same) and then see if OWASP has some workarounds or not, if not, there are lot of open source/free code available for this. For example, for using a captcha, Google provides [free captcha service](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) and likewise.